# Global Variable outside function not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, global-variables

I'm trying to use global variables outside the function. I tried almost everything and already I'v read many posts without progress. I'm trying to modify lightbox plugin and add there tags and social links by data-attribs.

Here is my HTML (method how I catch ids):

```
<a id="image-1" onclick="window.GetID(this.id)"
```

Here is my JS:

```
  var global;
  var tagList;
  var facebook;
  var twitter;
  var gplus;

  window.GetID = function (elem_id) {

    console.log(elem_id);
    global = document.getElementById(elem_id);
    console.log(global);
    tagList = global.getAttribute('data-tags');
    console.log(tagList);
    facebook = global.getAttribute('data-fb');
    console.log(facebook);
    twitter = global.getAttribute('data-tt');
    console.log(twitter);
    gplus = global.getAttribute('data-gplus');
    console.log(gplus);
    return;
  }

  Lightbox.prototype.build = function() {
    var self = this;
    $('<div id="lightboxOverlay" class="lightboxOverlay"></div><div id="lightbox" class="lightbox"><div class="lb-outerContainer"><div class="lb-container"><img class="lb-image" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" /><div class="lb-nav"><a class="lb-prev" href="" ></a><a class="lb-next" href="" ></a></div><div class="lb-loader"><a class="lb-cancel"></a></div></div></div><div class="lb-dataContainer"><div class="lb-data"><div class="lb-details"><ul class="tag-list">' + tagList + '</ul><br/><span class="lb-caption"></span><span class="lb-number"></span></div><div class="lb-closeContainer">' +
        '<ul class="social-list"><li><a href="' + facebook + '"><img src="img/fb_circle_white.png" class="img-responsive"></a></li><li><a href="' + twitter + '"><img src="img/tt_circle_white.png" class="img-responsive"></a></li><li><a href="' + gplus + '"><img src="img/gplus_circle_white.png" class="img-responsive"></a></li></ul><a class="lb-close"></a></div></div></div></div>').appendTo($('body'));
```

HTML is generate by javascript as you can see above.

Console log shows correct data. When I use variables outside the function I recieve undefined. I just need to get access to variables from function outside to finish it. Here is result of console log.

[image]

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with the problem so we could DEBUG it?

Comment: JavaScript variables are scoped based on functions, so if you declare a variable inside of a function, it won't be available outside the function. You need to either make a global variable outside of the function (not recommended, this will make your code messy) or pass the variable values as parameters to other functions that need them.